# Matrix logic, which theorems do I use?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics

I have a study problem in my linear algebra course that asks:

Suppose $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix with $\det(A) = 2$. Let $B = A^{-1}$, find $\det(A^TB^2)$.

It's a multiple choice question and the options are

> $a: 1/2$
>
> $b: 2$
>
> $c: 4$
>
> $d: 1/4$

How do I go about figuring this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\det(A^tB^2)=\det(A^t)\det(B^2)=\det(A)(\det B)^2 = \det(A)(\det A^{-1})^2 = \det(A)\Big(\dfrac{1}{\det A}\Big)^2$